# after enabled the c language layer it won't compile

Tags: spacevim

I followed the [official guide](https://spacevim.org/use-vim-as-a-c-cpp-ide/) to turned on the C language layer in space vim

but when I compile and run the code by **SPC l r** it tells me the key binding is not defined

I think this compile and run feature shall be turn on automatically by enable the layer. Is there any way to check the layer(corresponding plugins) are installed correctly

Answer (score 0):

first, make sure `lang#c` layer is loaded in you configuration file. you can open configuration file via `SPC f v d`, and Then restart your vim/neovim.

after restart vim, and then open a c file. you can use `SPC l r` now. please read `:h spacevim-layer-lang-c` for more info, or checkout the layer page:

http://spacevim.org/layers/lang/c/